# React/Redux - save select value onChange

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-router

I've created a Component that lets you Add/Remove a dropdown fields (onClick of two buttons). I'm using Redux to keep the state of the dropdown so that when I navigate back and forth (React Router) the added dropdowns are not lost.

Now I also need to keep the values of each dropdown onChange. So onChange I'm sending the value of the dropdowns to the reducer but it seems to be updating all the dropdowns at once (not individually).

Any idea how to fix this?

Here is my code so far:

**Component**

```
import React from 'react'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import uuidV4 from 'uuid-v4'
import { saveSelect, removeSelect, saveSelectValue, incrementCounter, decrementCounter } from '../actions.js'


class AccountUpgrade extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  addInput = (counter) => {
    this.props.saveSelect(uuidV4())
    this.props.incrementCounter(counter)
  }

  removeInput = (index, counter) => {
    this.props.removeSelect(index)
    this.props.decrementCounter(counter)
  }

  saveSelectValue = (e) => {
    let data = {}
    data = e.target.value

    this.props.saveSelectValue(data)
  }

  renderSelect = (id, index) => {
    const selectedValue = this.props.selectedValue || ''
    const counter = this.props.counter

    return(
      <div className="col-12">
        <select
          key={id}
          name={'document-'+ id}
          value={selectedValue}
          onChange = {this.saveSelectValue}
        >
          <option value="0">Please Select</option>
          <option value="1">Australia</option>
          <option value="2">France</option>
          <option value="3">United Kingdom</option>
          <option value="4">United States</option>
        </select>

        <button onClick={ () => {this.removeInput(index, counter) }}>Remove</button>
      </div>
    )
  }

  render(){
    const ids = this.props.ids || []
    const counter = this.props.counter

    return (
      <div>

        {this.props.counter <= 4 &&
          <button onClick={ this.addInput }>Add</button>
        }

        <div className="inputs">
          {ids.map(this.renderSelect)}
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    store: state.EligibleAbout,
    ids: state.EligibleAbout.ids,
    selectedValue: state.EligibleAbout.selectedValue,
    counter: state.EligibleAbout.counter,
  }
}

const EligibleAbout = connect(mapStateToProps, {saveSelect, removeSelect, saveSelectValue, incrementCounter, decrementCounter})(AccountUpgrade)

export default EligibleAbout
```

**action.js**

```
export const ADD_SELECT = 'ADD_SELECT'
export const REMOVE_SELECT = 'REMOVE_SELECT'
export const SAVE_SELECT_OPTION = 'SAVE_SELECT_OPTION'
export const INCREMENT_COUNTER = 'INCREMENT_COUNTER'
export const DECREMENT_COUNTER = 'DECREMENT_COUNTER'

export function saveSelect(data) {
  return { type: ADD_SELECT, data }
}

export function removeSelect(data) {
  return { type: REMOVE_SELECT, data }
}

export function saveSelectValue(data) {
  return { type: SAVE_SELECT_OPTION, data}
}

export function incrementCounter(data) {
    return { type: INCREMENT_COUNTER, data }
}

export function decrementCounter(data) {
    return { type: DECREMENT_COUNTER, data }
}
```

**reducer.js**

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux'
import { ADD_SELECT, REMOVE_SELECT, SAVE_SELECT_OPTION } from './actions'

function EligibleAbout(state = { ids: [], counter: 0, selectedValue: 'Please select'}, action = {}){
  switch (action.type){
    case ADD_SELECT:
      return {
        ...state,
        ids: [].concat(state.ids, action.data),
      }
    case REMOVE_SELECT:
      return {
        ...state,
        ids: state.ids.filter((id, index) => (index !== action.data)),
      }
    case SAVE_SELECT_OPTION:
      return {
        ...state,
        selectedValue: action.data
      }
    case INCREMENT_COUNTER:
      return {
        ...state,
        counter: state.counter + 1
      }
    case DECREMENT_COUNTER:
      return {
        ...state,
        counter: state.counter - 1
      }
    default:
      return state
  }
}

const FormApp = combineReducers({
  EligibleAbout
})

export default FormApp
```

Comment: `but it seems to be updating all the dropdowns at once (not individually).` What do you mean by this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you need to keep the selected value for each id or dropdown, the best approach would be keeping an object array with objects which have `id` and `value` property instead of having string array `ids`. So you will have to change your code into something like this. I didn't test the code, so let me know in comments if you get any issue with it.

```
class AccountUpgrade extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  addInput = () => {
    this.props.saveSelect({id:uuidV4()})
  }

  removeInput = (index) => {
    this.props.removeSelect(index)
  }

  saveSelectValue = (e, id) => {
    let data = {}
    data.id = id;
    data.value = e.target.value

    this.props.saveSelectValue(data)
  }

  renderSelect = (selection, index) => {
    const selectedValue = selection.value || '';
    const id = selection.id;

    return(
      <div className="col-12">
        <select
          key={id}
          name={'document-'+ id}
          value={selectedValue}
          onChange = {(e) => this.saveSelectValue(e, id)}
        >
          <option value="0">Please Select</option>
          <option value="1">Australia</option>
          <option value="2">France</option>
          <option value="3">United Kingdom</option>
          <option value="4">United States</option>
        </select>

        <button onClick={ () => {this.removeInput(index) }}>Remove</button>
      </div>
    )
  }

  render(){
    const selections = this.props.selections || []

    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={ this.addInput }>Add</button>

        <div className="inputs">
          {selections.map(this.renderSelect)}
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    store: state.EligibleAbout,
    selections: state.EligibleAbout.selections,
  }
}
```

You need to modify your reducer as well.

```
function EligibleAbout(state = { selections: [] } , action = {}){
  switch (action.type){
    case ADD_SELECT:
      return {
        ...state,
        selections: [].concat(state.selections, action.data),
      }
    case REMOVE_SELECT:
      return {
        ...state,
        selections: state.selections.filter((selection, index) => (index !== action.data)),
      }
    case SAVE_SELECT_OPTION:
      return {
        ...state,
        selections: state.selections.map((selection) => selection.id === action.data.id ? action.data : selection)
      }
    default:
      return state
  }
}
```

Comment: It makes sense - it worked fine. Thanks for explaining and for the example.

Comment: I know it's related to the question but how could you restrict the dropdowns to be added only 5 times?

Comment: You can simply check the `selections` count before adding a new one. `addInput = () => {
  if(this.props.selections.length <= 5) {
    this.props.saveSelect({id:uuidV4()})
  }else{
    //Message
  }
}`

Comment: Took a slightly different approach - let me know if it's a good approach. I created a counter which I linked to the store and I show and hide Add button depending on the counter value. I've updated my code.

Comment: I can't understand why you have to use a counter and set of additional state changes to track the data that is already available. I think you can simply do that with the length of your element array. `{this.props.ids.length <= 4 &&
          <button onClick={ this.addInput }>Add</button>
        }`

Comment: Ah. I was clearly over engineering. I implemented your previous solution, so you are right, I could just do: {this.props.selections.length < 5 && <button onClick={ this.addInput }>Add</button> }

Comment: Hey Tharaka, any chance you could take a look at this question I asked -
 it's related to this topic so perhaps you can help:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44640679/react-multiple-components-with-the-same-actions-reducers

Answer (score 1):

You are only storing one selected value that they all read from.  You'll want to give each select an ID of some sort and save / recall it's selected state specifically. Something like:

```
   case SAVE_SELECT_OPTION:
      return {
        ...state,
        selectedValues: {
          [action.selectID]: action.data
        }
      }
```

Of course you'll need to update your dispatch and actions accordingly.